# How to print (with a printer) a NSTextView text content without background and text color attribute?

Tags: swift, macos, printing, nstextview

I'm trying to print with a printer, the plain text content of a NSTextView which has a black background and a white text (no images, only unformatted text).

I'm using this code:

```
mainTextField.print(Any?.self)
```

Unfortunately the print (preview) looks like black with a white text on it, apart from that I would use an ink of cartridge for each paper, it is not good even for the environment. Is there a way to just print the text without background and text color attributes?

Comment: Why don't you use NSPrintInfo?

Comment: Hi El Tomato, because I'm learning to program with Swift and NSPrintInfo seems to me a too much advanced topic due my little experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new NSTextView when you want to print.

```
@IBAction func printButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let tv = NSTextView(frame: textView.frame)
    tv.string = textView.string
    tv.print(tv)
}
```

--- Update: with rich text.---

```
@IBAction func printButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let tv = NSTextView(frame: textView.frame)
    if textView.isRichText {
        let data = textView.rtf(from: NSMakeRange(0, (textView.string! as NSString).length))
        tv.replaceCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0, 0), withRTF: data!)
        tv.textColor = .black
    }
    else {
        tv.string = textView.string
    }

    tv.print(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Owen Zhao

Comment: With Swift 4, I needed to change 'tv.print(tv)' with 'tv.printView(tv)'

Answer (score -2):

In my project, I print the text content of a text view via the codes. Swift 4 on iOS 10

```
func printContent() {
    let printer = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printer.printFormatter = UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(attributedText: self.contentView.attributedText)

    printer.present(animated: true) { printer, success, error in
        print("print success: \(success)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not provide a solution for the question above and it is for mobile not for mac os cocoa.